# Can I push a smart pointer to a list of smart pointers?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, std, shared-ptr

I have the following code:

```
class MarchingEvent
{
...
};

typedef std::list< std::shared_ptr<MarchingEvent> > Segment;
```

Can I do:

```
void myFunction(std::shared_ptr<MarchingEvent> A)
{
    Segment segment;
    segment.push_back( A ); // <- Questionable line.
}
```

Will my smart pointer be correctly incremented when pushing **A** to **segment**?

Comment: Why not checking that yourself? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/use_count

Comment: If you see `std::shared_ptr` as a form of *ownership* then by adding the pointer to the list you now have added an owner of the `MarchingEvent`.

Comment: On an unrelated note, the "default" container should almost always be `std::vector`. Only if you have special requirements you should use other containers or container adaptors.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: this works great thanks! And yes the smart pointer is correctly  handled when pushing it to the list.

Comment: _"Will my smart pointer be correctly incremented when pushing A to segment?"_ What makes you doubt that it will work correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will my smart pointer be correctly incremented when pushing A to segment?

Yes. That's what `std::shared_ptr` is supposed to do.

Note, however, that if you don't use the object `A` after the call to `push_back`, you might want to change the last line to

```
segment.push_back(std::move(A));
```

to move-construct the element in `segment` instead of copying it - the copying has already been done upon entry of the function, because `A` is passed by value.

Comment: Knowing that my data is a pointer, the move is not really helpful, is it?

Comment: No, the performance hit doesn't come from the pointer being copy- instead of move-constructed, but the control block of the `std::share_ptr`. This part of the smart pointer is cheaper to move.